# automatically find the set of array in php class object

Tags: php, object

How can I skip the var collection in an object when I use `foreach`

```
Samp Object
     (
       [collection] => Array
          (
              [0] => Array
               (
                 [fname] => "john", 
                 [lname] => "peter"
               )
              [1] => Array
               (
                 [fname] => "simon", 
                 [lname] => "peter"
               )
          )
     )
```

whenever I foreach the object it must find the set of array automatically and must skip the "collection"

```
$samp = new Samp();

foreach ($samp as $row){
   print_r($row)
}
```

the result must be like this

```
       Array
           (
            [fname] => "john", 
            [lname] => "peter"
           )
       Array
           (
            [fname] => "simon", 
            [lname] => "peter"
           )
```

but whenever I do the `foreach` the result is like this

```
[collection] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
              (
                [fname] => "john", 
                [lname] => "peter"
               )
            [1] => Array
              (
                [fname] => "simon", 
                [lname] => "peter"
               )
        )
```

I need to do this first to get the result

```
$samp = new Samp();

foreach ($samp->collection as $row){
   print_r($row)
}
```

Or this

```
$samp = new Samp();

foreach ($samp as $row => $value){
   print_r($value)
}
```

but I want to skip the collection how can I do that? laravel frame work did that... I need it to my new class

here is the class code

```
class Samp
{
    public $collection;

    public function samp($no)
    {
        $this->collection = array(["fname"=>"john","lname"=>"peter"],["fname"=>"simon","lname"=>"peter"]);
        return $this;
    }

    public function pagination(){

    }

}
```

so i can use the object to another function like this

```
$samp = new Samp();

foreach ($samp as $row){
   echo $row['fname']." ".$row['lname'];
}

echo $samp->pagination();
```

Comment: May be this `foreach ($samp as $key => $value){ print_r($value); }`

Comment: Can you provide the code for your `Samp` class? It looks like your info is stored in a property of the class called `collection` and needs to be accessed that way.

Comment: it must automatically foreach the array without using $samp->collection, just using $samp and it will go automatic in $samp->collection.. how to do that in oo?p